# RESTEasy - @Path requiring a full path?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I was messing around with JAX-RS and made an application which calls REST services which produce JSON. I tried Jersey and everything went fine, but I had to switch to RESTEasy as my application needs to be built with JDK5. I changed my web.xml to something like this:

```
<web-app>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```

So I expect every URL starting with /rest to be handled by RESTEasy. My services are as follows:

```
@Path("/services")
public class MyRESTServices {

    @GET
    @Path("service1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object service1(Blah blah) {

    }
}
```

This worked fine using Jersey, http://localhost/MyContext/rest/services/service1 was bound to my service1() method. When I change to RESTEasy, though, I had a 404:

> HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /rest/services/service1 of full path: http://localhost/MyContext/rest/services/service1

Which means that RESTEasy handled the request but could not find any service bound to this URL.

On my class, changing `@Path("/services")` to `@Path("/rest/services")` worked, though. Do you have any idea why I got this strange behaviour? All the tutorials/docs I read mentionned only relative paths, not including the /rest prefix...

Comment: How are you configuring RESTEasy internally? With CXF, I have to configure the removal of the `/rest` fragment in my Spring config file.

Comment: I don't configure anything else that what you can see in the web.xml (scan for annotations). I'll see if the removal can be configured.

Comment: Shame on me, it was right in front of me in the docs:

"The resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix <context param> variable must be set if your servlet-mapping for the Resteasy servlet has a url-pattern other than /*"

Comment: I dont think it is strange. Your regular expression does not mention anything about /rest path so resteasy cant know about it if you dont add it to regular exp or web.xml as a prefix.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solution: add the following in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Where /rest is the beginning of your `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`

(Source: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#d0e72)

Comment: Thanks.  Your "Where..." sentence is what straightened me out.  I was using /rest/* in the param-value element.

Comment: @Nebelmann I want to have my url `"http://localhost:8080/MyContent/rest/services/service1"` as `"http://localhost:8080/MyContent/services/service1"` i dont want to have rest in my url pattern. Can you help me out how to define that

Answer (score 0):

On JBoss AS 7.1 I also had to add to add
 resteasy.resources ...
which is further explained here
http://www.javaroots.com/2013/05/creating-rest-services-with-rest-easy.html 
You may get error like this : Could not find resource for relative : /application/test of full path:... 
You have to define resteasy.resource context param with the full path of Rest class.