# Tomcat not serving static files

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, web.xml, gradle-tomcat-plugin

I'm at the end of my rope on this one. I'm try to get a super simple webapp up and I can't seem to get tomcat to not 404 static files.

- I'm using the gradle tomcat plugin with tomcat version 7.0.39
- My html file is at `hey-world/src/main/webapp/index.html`
- My `web.xml` looks like this:

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
          <param-value>HeyWorldApplication</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

So I thought this setup would map `localhost:8080/hey-world/static/index.html` to the file, but it 404's everytime. Is this a problem with some convention in the gradle tomcat plugin?

Comment: A url-pattern defines what URLs map to what servlets, it does not define the path to static data files -- and in fact it shouldn't do so.

Comment: @fge Since this won't be production code, I'm less concerned with the performance hits of serving static files from tomcat. Likewise for the security concerns of potentially allowing access to `WEB-INF` (which if I understand correctly has been fixed in this version of tomcat?). My understanding is that routing some `url-pattern` to the default servlet would serve files out of the `webapp` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL-patterns used in `web.xml`/`servlet-mapping` is often a little simplistic. I think in your case, the `/*` pattern for Resteasy will work as a catch-all, so that no other mapping will really matter.

For debugging, I suggest you remove the Resteasy-servlet altogether, and see if you can serve static files from a custom URL with your mapping.
If that works, re-enable Resteasy, but on a different URL-pattern (eg. `/rest/*`).

If that works, well, then everything really works fine, it's just that the URL-mapping for `/*` blocks anything else from working.

The easiest solution would probably be to server static files as per default (no mapping), and serve rest-stuff from another URL.

Alternatively use two web apps. One with context root `/static`, one with context root `/`.

Comment: So commenting out `Resteasy` did start serving the file but at `localhost:8080/hey-world/index.html`, but still 404ed `localhost:8080/hey-world/static/index.html` which makes me think the problem is in the static mapping?

Comment: Why not just put index.html inside a "static" folder in your webapp? Easy solutions always win. ;-)

Comment: Okay now I don't think the servlet mappings are doing anything at all.  I switched the static files to not use a mapping and put Resteasy at `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>` and now it serves the static files fine but 404s `localhost:8080/hey-world/api/path-to-resteasy-stuff`

Comment: Oop. If you put Resteasy behind another url you need to provide a `<context-param>` [that specifies what that is.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131968/resteasy-path-requiring-a-full-path) Everything is working now. Thanks!