# Paths not handled by services throwing javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly

I am porting a REST layer to Wildfly/RESTEasy from Tomcat/Jersey.  I have only begun to stub out the REST layer but it works.  The only problem I am having so far is when I call an unhanded resource path that starts the root api path.

For example:

`http://localhost:8080/tmoi-0.0.1/api2/account`

matches my only resource and returns a valid json object.

`http://localhost:8080/tmoi-0.0.1/notanapi`

also behaves as expected since it does not match the path set out in the `@ApplicationPath("/api2")` and so returns a 404 with a body that says "Not Found" and nothing is logged on the server. But:

`http://localhost:8080/tmoi-0.0.1/api2/account2`

matches the ApplicationPath but no specific resource and ends up throwing this exception on the server:

```
[0m[33m16:27:19,852 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-9) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/tmoi-0.0.1/api2/account2
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
```

There is no `web.xml` configuration.  My `Application` class looks like this.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api2")
public class TMOIApplication extends Application {
}
```

My one resource is this:

```
@Path("account")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AccountService {
    @GET
    public NewAccount getAccount() {
        return new NewAccount("test");
    }

}
```

So why do I get the exception when I call the `/api2/account2` instead of just returning a normal 404?

## Update

I tested this on the Quickstart example [Helloword-RS](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-rs) and it shows the same behavior. I ran across this post [RESTEasy - @Path requiring a full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131968/resteasy-path-requiring-a-full-path?rq=1) that documents similar behavior.  I guess my question now is:

**Is there a NO-XML way to solve this or am I going to have to use the `web.xml` to pass parameters to RESTEasy?**

This is a the more recent [link](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#d4e125) to the docs referenced in the answer.

## Update 2

Even though this has been answered, I would like to not that the web.xml answer makes no difference in resources that it can't locate under the root resource.  Apparently, throwing an exception rather than just returning a 404 is the normal behavior as pointed out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour for handling exceptions is to log the stack trace and respond with a HTML page containing status code and message. The user does get the right HTTP status code but in many cases the error page is unnecessary when creating an API.

If you want to provide your own behaviour for handling any exceptions, you can need to use an [ExceptionMapper](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html).

From the [Resteasy Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html#ExceptionMappers):

> You may override Resteasy built-in exceptions by writing an ExceptionMapper for the exception. For that matter, you can write an ExceptionMapper for any thrown exception including WebApplicationException

Comment: I agree but the exception is being thrown somewhat randomly.  Notice that it is only thrown for urls that have a base resource that is the same as the one defined in @ApplicationPath.  I guess I am wondering if this conforms to the JSR.

Comment: Ok I see. I don't know if this is specified anywhere but I would expect this behaviour. The webapp/servlet uses path `api2` so it handles all requests for this path and any sub paths, even if they throw a 404. Other request have to be processed by other servlets, or the servlet container if there aren't any registered for a path. I think it makes sense that whatever servlet processes a path should be responsible for thrown exceptions and returning appropriate http responses.

Comment: Fair enough.  It's not a huge deal but it worries me that the exception might be used to easily DDOS a server.  Maybe not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AccountService` class should be annotated with `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` (or an EJB annotation such as `javax.ejb.Stateless` if you want to access an underlying JPA Entity Manager for example).

HTH.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't gotten that far yet.